# Eclipse - Pydev Code Completion (Unable to create the selected preference page)

Tags: eclipse, pydev, code-completion

I recently noticed that while using Eclipse, every keystroke I typed caused the code completion to kick in.  I checked the `PyDev --> Editor --> Code Completion` tab, where it should have the time delay setting for auto-complete.

I get this error:

[image: Error message]

```
Unable to create the selected preference page.

org.python.pydev.ast.codecompletion.PyCodeCompletionPreferencesPage 
cannot be found by org.python.pydev_6.3.1.201802272029
```

I tried uninstalling/re-installing the PyDev module from within Eclipse, but I still get the same issue.  I can access the Code Completion setting for Java/JavaScript/..., but not PyDev any more.

Eclipse Oxygen.2 Release (4.7.2)
PyDev for Eclipse 6.3.1.201802272029

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that. This is a bug in PyDev 6.3.1.

I'll make sure it's fixed in PyDev 6.3.2.

Comment: No problemo. What's the ETA for that?

Comment: Hopefully within this week, but it may slip into the next.

Comment: @FabioZadrozny, I'm trying to install PyDev 7.4.0.201910251334 in Eclipse Luna JEE (Ubuntu 16.04), and I got this same error when I try to configure it using Window -> Preference -> PyDev -> Interpreters -> Python Interpreter. (and thanks for PyDev for Eclipse, it's excellent!!!)

Comment: @Alex8752 The problem in this case is that Luna is too old. My suggestion is that you get a newer version of Eclipse from eclipse.org.

Comment: @FabioZadrozny, thank you for your (ultra-) fast response. I spent all night long, but I found a solution to this issue (in PyDev site, of course). I installed PyDev 5.2 from the PyDev site, and everything is now working!!! By the way, I still use Eclipse Luna JEE because that is the last version with full support for Javascript code autocompletion.